# Microsoft Dynamics CRM update number field from another entity

Tags: javascript, forms, dynamics-crm, onload

Can anyone help me with a JS code where I can update a number filed during a record creation?

For example: You have an entity call **cars** that have a number value "**current mileage**" and another entity called **rental** that has two number filed for car section (**current mileage** and **received mileage**).

**Current mileage** will store the mileage value of the **selected car** (example 300) and the **received mileage** will be manually inputted by the sales person (for example 100).

So when the sale person **created a new rental** record, and OnUpdate of the Car lookup field the Current mileage will show the sales person the current mileage of the selected car (300) in this case, so he just will need to add the new value (100). Next time when he create a rental and select from the looup the same car, the Current mileage will be populated with 400 (300+100), and so on.

I see this as JScript OnUpdate of the Car lookup filed, but i really dont know how to write such a code, i hope someone can give me a hint. I'm planning to reuse the code for other entities following the same logic.

I have the following JS code in DYnamics CRM attached on change of a lookupfiled:

new_car - (lookup) to select a car from the rental entity
new_cars - schema name of the cars entity
new_carsid - UUID of the car from the car entity
new_totally_used - total mileage of a car
new_outgoing_value - filed on the rental record where must the totally used value appears upon selection of a car

```
    function retrieveCarsDetails() {
//read lookup value
if (Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_car").getValue() != null && Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_car").getValue()[0].id != null) {
  var new_carsid = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_car").getValue()[0].id;
new_carsid=new_carsid.replace('{','').replace('}','');
  //pass entity, fields, we can use expand to get related entity fields
  Xrm.WebApi.retrieveRecord("new_cars", new_carsid, "?$select=new_totally_used").then(
    function success(result) {
      if (result != null) {
        //set text field
        if (result["new_outgoing_value"] != null)
          Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_totally_used").setValue(result["new_outgoing_value"]);
      }
    },
    function(error) {
      alert(error.message);
    }
  );
}
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new field(sum of current and received mileage) in the Rental entity. Update this new sum field, when the sales person updates the received mileage.

So, when the lookup is selected in the car entity, retrieve the sum field from the Rental entity and update the Current mileage in the Car entity with Sum field of Rental entity.

Comment: I already have filed for current mileage which should get the value from the car totally used filed upon car lookup select.

Comment: what is the issue you are facing, can you explain in detail or provide screenshot?

Comment: I have the following JS code in DYnamics CRM attached on change of a lookup filed:

Comment: Not sure which version of CRM you are on, but if you download Dataverse REST Builder from XrmToolBox and you can generate code.
https://www.xrmtoolbox.com/plugins/GuidoPreite.DRB/